# Getting values from Data in Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
type Name = String
type Age = age
data Person = P Name Age derieving (eq)
type People = [Person]

smiths = [P "John" 21, P "Willy" 26]
```

How to get Johns age? Is there any function like (smiths!!0).age? Or is it only possible with pattern matching?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can perform pattern matching:

```
(\(P _ a) -> a) (smiths !! 0)
```

But it might be better to define `Person` with record syntax:

```
data Person = P {
    name :: Name
  , age :: Age
  } deriving Eq
```

Then Haskell will automatically construct a "getter" `age :: Person -> Age`, and then you can access this with:

```
age (smiths !! 0)
```